# PSR Standard One statement per line

Tags: php, psr-2

Is this 2 statements or 1?

```
if ($a == "A" && $b == "B") { // do something }
```

How do I use two statements if I want to follow PSR standards? Should I use multiple if's? Like if inside an if?

Comment: I'd just do what feels right for you, as long as you remain consistent to your own rules. The PSR "standards" are a load of horse crap anyway.

Comment: The things inside the parens are expressions. Within the curlys you have statements. The `if` itself is a control construct. More importantly you shouldn't blindly follow coding styles, but apply what makes sense, and deviate when necessary to aid readability.

Comment: Two statements per line would be `foo(); bar();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply should look like this:

```
if ($a == "A" && $b == "B") {


}
```

You don't need to create multiple ifs

If you have longer conditions you could use such syntax:

```
<?php

if ($a == "A"
    && $b == "B"
) {


}
```

Both of them were tested in PhpStorm when code style is set to PSR

Comment: @LovebRazil Yes, this is one statement. Multiple would be `$a = 5; $b = 10;` and it is not PSR compliant because these are 2 statements in one line